# NoMatchReverse error ListView to DetailView can't seem to pass url parameters

Tags: django, python-3.x, reverse, django-urls

I have been struggling with this problem for over a day now. I truly don't understand what to look for when it comes to NoReverseMatch errors. Every time I supply an answer to the error, i get a new error that I don't know how to deal with. Would really appreciate some help with understanding how to debug this issue because I am at a loss right now.

I am building a website that has two apps. 1. The main website and 2. a Blog. I created the blog app recently and hooked up the urls so that from the home page, you can go to the blog home (a listview) and then all I want is to make it so that users can click on the title of the article that interests them, and it will display the text and other info associated with the article. The problem is I continually keep getting NoReverseMatch errors on either the blog home page or the blog detail view page and I have no idea where to even begin in troubleshooting it. I am new to OOP, Django, and python and so this is all very disorienting.

My most recent error I have been getting is

```
NoReverseMatch at /blog/
Reverse for 'blog_post_detail' with keyword arguments '{'title': 'Another One'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/articles/(?P<title>[\\.\\w-]+)/$']
```

main urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/login/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include(('blog.urls', 'blog'), namespace='blog')),
    path('', include(('website.urls', 'main'), namespace='main')),
]
```

blog urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path, reverse

from .views import BlogHomeView, BlogDetailView

app_name= 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^articles/(?P<title>[\.\w-]+)/$', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='blog_post_detail'),
    re_path(r'^$', BlogHomeView.as_view(), name='blog_home'),

    ]
```

blog views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector, SearchQuery, SearchRank
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from .models import ArticlePosts, ArticleCategories
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


# Create your views here.


class BlogHomeView(ListView):
    template_name = 'blog/blog_home.html'
    model = ArticlePosts
    context_object_name = "blog_articles"

class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'blog/blog_post_detail.html'
    model = ArticlePosts
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from pathlib import Path
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse


class ArticleCategories(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created at")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Updated at")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Title")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class ArticlePosts(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created at")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Updated at")
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Is published?")
    published_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False, verbose_name="Published at")
    category = models.ForeignKey(ArticleCategories, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', verbose_name="Author", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Title")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Description", default="All content is created by our founders.")
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name="Text")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', default="static/static/img/default.jpg")
    fig_caption = models.TextField(default="Default Image", verbose_name="Caption")
    def slug(self):
        return slugify(self.title)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Post"
        verbose_name_plural = "Posts"
        ordering = ['-created_at']

    def publish(self):
        self.is_published = True
        self.published_at = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:blog_post_detail', kwargs={'title': self.title})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

blog_home.html:

```
<img src="{% static 'static/img/ssg600.png' %}" alt="About us" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail pull-right m-l m-b" width=150px height=150px> -->
            {% for post in blog_articles %}
            <div class="block block-border-bottom-grey block-pd-sm">
            <h3 class="block-title" id="nursing">
                <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><b>{{ post.title }}</b></a>
              </h3>
            <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" alt="Services" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail pull-left m-l m-b" width=150px height=150px>
            {{ post.description|linebreaks }}
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
```

base.html:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'blog:blog_home' %}" tabindex="-1" class="menu-item">Check Out our Blog</a></li>


Before I posted this I had had get_absolute_url set to this:
```

def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:blog_post_detail', kwargs={'slug': slugify(self.title)})

```
But it gave me a slugfield error. So I switched it to title, and now I have this error:
```

NoReverseMatch at /blog/
Reverse for 'blog_post_detail' with keyword arguments '{'title': 'Another One'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/articles/(?P[\.\w-]+)/$']

```
I would really appreciate any help on this.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

- Django convention is to name classes in the singular form: 
  `ArticleCategory`, `ArticlePost`
- Instead of defining `slug()` as a method, you should define a `slug` field and set the value in a `save()` override
- `<title>` in the url is expecting a slug, so you should be passing `self.slug` (after you've created the `slug` field)

So then this:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:blog_post_detail', kwargs={'title': self.title})
```

would change to:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:blog_post_detail', kwargs={'title': self.slug})
```

HOWEVER, instead of defining `get_absolute_url()`, I would just render the template like this (be sure to include `{% load static %}` at the top of the template file):

```
<h3 class="block-title" id="nursing">
    <a href="{% url 'blog_post_detail' post.slug %}"><b>{{ post.title }}</b></a>
</h3>
```

Comment: See thats the thing, I had been doing it like that^ and I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError at /blog/articles/another-one/
Generic detail view BlogDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.
```

Here is my code:
```
<a href="{% url 'blog:blog_post_detail' post.slug %}"><b>{{ post.title }}</b></a>
```

and the edited get_absolute_url:
```
 def get_absolute_url(self):
  return reverse('blog:blog_post_detail', kwargs={'title': self.slug})
```

Comment: Its like it isn't passing the slug name into the URL.

Comment: I did what you recommended. Added a slug-field and that solved the problem. I just don't get what happened because I had creaed anther website before using the same model and it worked just fine. The models.py was also very similar and the post-detail worked right away. I don't know why it had a hard time determing the slug field in this case compared with the last time I used it. Thanks for the help. Such a dumb thing to overlook.